# Is there a description of the points of the Cantor set on which the Cantor function is differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, fractals

Let $C$ be the usual ternary cantor set, and $f$ the Cantor function, or Devil’s staircase associated to it. We know that $f$ is differentiable a.e., and on every point of the complement $C^c$, the derivative is $0$. Is there a description of the set of points of $C$ on which $f$ is differentiable? And can we identify the derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can characterize the Cantor set as the set of $x \in [0,1]$ which have a base-$3$ expansion $x = \sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i 3^{-i}$ where all $x_i \in \{0,2\}$.  The Cantor function on $C$ is then $f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty (x_i/2) 2^{-i}$.  Now if $x \in C$,
you can get $y \in C$ with $|x - y| = 2 \cdot 3^{-k}$ by flipping the $k$'th digit:
$y_i = x_i$ except $y_k = 2-x_i$; and $|f(x) - f(y)| = 2^{-k}$.  Since $\dfrac{2^{-k}}{2 \cdot 3^{-k}} \to \infty$ as $k \to \infty$, $f$ is never differentiable at any $x\in C$.

Comment: Hm, this would seem to contradict the fact that the points of nondifferentiability of the Cantor function have Hausdorff dimension $(\log 2/ \log 3)^2$ (while the Cantor set has Hausdorff dimension $\log 2/ \log 3$). See e.g. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2159830?origin=crossref&seq=1. However I can’t seem to find anything wrong with your argument either..

Comment: The Darst paper counts both right and left derivative ${} = +\infty$ as "differentiable".  Robert does not.  Darst says paper reference [4] characterizes the points of differentiability.

Comment: "Can we identify the derivative?"  Answer: $+\infty$ at points of $C$ where it exists.

Comment: @Nate River: Pages 28-31 of [this paper](https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/oleg_zaboronski/analysisiii/cantor.pdf) gives a nice survey, and some of the references in [this question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677927/bibliography-for-singular-functions) may also be of use.

Comment: Ah, that settles it nicely @GeraldEdgar, thanks! Also Dave L Renfro, thanks for the extensive biblography. It seems they have taken a similar approach as Robert did in the paper to compute the Dini derivatives.